# JavaScript Runtime Error: Couldn't set Value property of Reference that undefined or null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, datalist

(i try to translate my trouble Turkish to English. "JavaScript çalışma zamanı hatası: Tanımsız veya boş referansın 'value' özelliği ayarlanamıyor" in Turkish. I wrote this note to understand me better if you know Turkish)
I try to pass selected gridview row's information to Datalist's ItemTemplate's table following codes

```
    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewVehicleList.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                // set the last parameter to true 
                // to register for event validation. 
                row.Attributes["onclick"] =
                 ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridViewVehicleList,
                    "select$" + row.DataItemIndex, true);
            }
        }
        base.Render(writer);
    }


    protected void OnRowSelected(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the datakey of the selected row
        var id = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewVehicleList.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value);
        var id2 = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewVehicleList.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Values[1]); 

        SqlDataSourceVehicleListForDatalist.SelectCommand = string.Format("SELECT *" +
            " FROM CURRENTDATA WHERE DATEANDTIME = {0} AND RFID = {1}", id,id2 );
        DataListVehicleList.DataBind();

        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 4;
    }
```

but i take above mistake

How to get over this issue

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is where you are getting object from local resource file. May be in `code behind` or may be in `JS`. Properly check that `GetLocalResourceObject("key")` string exits in resource file and has value.

Comment: Yes,you are right Afnan Ahmad. I found following Script files cause this problem from aspx page.                                          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: However i need these files for some mobile design. What can i do?

Comment: @osmanedip I think the problem is not in above these two files. Is there any other `JS` file which you are using ?

Comment: if i removed these script codes library, i havent taken this mistake. But my mobile design cant implement based on this situation.

Comment: i need to show any selected gridview's row information inside a datalist. Could any other code or script provide to me?

Comment: @osmanedip the problem is in your own custom `JS` file where you are trying to get local resource object in `alert` or in `confirm`.